Upload image file from react native to C# backend
I am trying to upload image file (any type) from react native Android app frontend to C# backend code.
Here is my react native code:
import * as ImagePicker from "expo-image-picker";

export default function AdminPortal() {
const [image, setImage] = useState<ImagePicker.ImagePickerResult | null>(null);

const handleSubmit = () => {
const formData = new FormData();

if (image && !image.canceled) {
  const fileUri = image.assets[0].uri;
  const fileType = image.assets[0].type; 
  const fileName = image.assets[0].fileName; 

  formData.append("file", {
     uri: fileUri, 
     type: fileType, 
     name: fileName, 
   });
}
  fetch('http://192.168.4.25:7018/post', { 
  method: 'POST',
  body: formData,
})
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((response) => {
    console.log('upload succes', response);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('upload error', error);
  });

Alert.alert("Data submitted", JSON.stringify(data));

// navigation.goBack();  

};
    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
          <Text style={styles.header}>Admin Page</Text>
          <Pressable style={styles.button} onPress={handleImageUpload}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Upload Image</Text>
          </Pressable>
          {image && !image.canceled && (
            <Text>Image selected: {image.assets[0].fileName}</Text>
          )}
         <Pressable style={styles.submitButton} onPress={handleSubmit}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Submit</Text>
          </Pressable>
        </SafeAreaView>

Here is my backend code for C#:
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(IFormFile file)
{
    try
    {
        var imageUrl = new ImageHandler(_cloudinary).ImageUploader(file);
        _logger.LogInformation("A new post has been created");
        return Ok(new { message = "A new post has been created" });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return StatusCode(500, new { message = ex.Message });
    }
}

Other information:

I can see my other API are working fine with other types and the app is connected to the back end.
The back end code looks ok as I can also hit the breakpoint from PostMan with a file selected.

Can anyone please help me with this been nearly two days trying to solve this?

Try using [FromForm] in your method parameters.
public async Task<ActionResult> Create([FromForm] IFormFile file) 
{
    //...
}

[FromForm] represent the files and from datas which you send from client. If you want to understand check this reading.

Hi Musa, I have tried it before but did not work.

Hi, did you try also send with MultipartFormDataContent

expo always has some or the other problems. try using
import ImageCropPicker from 'react-native-image-crop-picker';
eg.
ImageCropPicker.openCamera({
width: 1024,  // Increase dimensions for better quality
height: 1024,  // Increase dimensions for better quality
cropping: true,
cropperCircleOverlay: false,
compressImageQuality: 0.9,  // Reduce compression for higher quality (closer to 1 is better)
includeBase64: true,  // If you need base64 for the payload, keep this true
})
